# Базы данных в Delphi

Tags: delphi, книги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какой литературе подробно описано подключение базы данных MS ACCESS в Делфи

Comment: вопрос несколько не правильно сформулирован, наверное вы имели ввиду что бы **использовать** базы данных

Comment: вы правы я не так сформулировал свой вопрос ... вы можете подсказать в какой литературе подробно описание подключение базы данных написаную на MS ACCESS в программный код Делфи

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с MS Access лучше использовать технологию [ADO](http://www.sql.ru/articles/mssql/2005/122703ADO.shtml). Книжку по Delphi без труда найдешь в интернете.

Answer (score 1):

**Delphi Глазами Хакера (Фленов)**

**Программирование в Delphi 7 (Культин)**

Я лично учился с статей, т.к. их легче воспринимать чем книги (книги в основном не для обучения,а для копипаста программного кода - лишь Культин ещё более-менее норм).

В Яндекс вбейте "Delphi создание БД"